# Only pass an argument to a function if it takes that argument Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have a 'validate' method which works like so:

```
def validate(self, allow_deferred_fields=False):
    """
    Validate the data in the group.
    Raises ValidationError if there is any incorrect data.
    """
    # Check custom validation of current group
    self.custom_validation()
```

And the custom_validation method differs depending on which group is being validated. One of my custom_validation definitions I would like to pass the argument 'allow_deferred_fields' like so:

```
def custom_validation(self, allow_deferred_fields=False):
    if allow_deferred_fields:
    .... some code
```

but the other custom_validation methods do not take this parameter. How can I pass this parameter into the custom_validation call within the validate method without having to add it as a parameter to all the other custom_validation methods it could potentially call?

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand what you are trying to say, can you please add definition of other custom_validator? Have you gone through `**kwargs, *args` ? Do you know about method overloading in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design issue. Currently, part of `validate`'s "contract" is that it will call a method `custom_validation` with zero arguments. You need to either change `validate` to accept additional arguments to pass on:

```
def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.custom_validation(*args, **kwargs)
```

or you need to "embed" the flag in the object itself so that `custom_validation` can access it when called.

```
def validate(self):
    self.custom_validation()

def custom_validation(self):
    if self.allow_deferred_fields:
        ...

...
obj.allow_deferred_fields = True
obj.validate()
```

The second option is a bit of a hack, though. It's not much better than having a global variable that `custom_validation` checks.

The third option is to force *all* custom validation methods to accept (possibly arbitrary) keyword arguments when called by `validate`, though they are free to ignore the argument.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is pretty hard to check if the function takes the parameter (see inspect.signature) but it is very easy to call the function and catch an error if it doesn't support the parameter, **provided you know the function will never raise a TypeError**.

This has the advantage of also working with C-based functions.

```py
def validate(self, allow_deferred_fields=False):
    """
    Validate the data in the group.
    Raises ValidationError if there is any incorrect data.
    """
    # Check custom validation of current group
    try:
        self.custom_validation(allow_deferred_fields=True)
    except TypeError:
        self.custom_validation()
```

If you can't rely on the function never throwing a TypeError, you could try the following, but bear in mind it will fail if the function is implemented in C

```py
def validate(self, allow_deferred_fields=False):
    """
    Validate the data in the group.
    Raises ValidationError if there is any incorrect data.
    """
    # Check custom validation of current group
    if "allow_deferred_fields" in inspect.signature(self.custom_validation):
        self.custom_validation(allow_deferred_fields=True)
    else:
        self.custom_validation()
```